# Object value getting passed among methods

Tags: objective-c, object

If i make a property such as:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *RSSIvalue;
```

and then i synthesize it:

```
@synthesize RSSIvalue;
```

Can i then define it as something in one method:

```
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
{
RSSIvalue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)RSSI.integerValue];
}
```

And then use that value i defined it as in another method:

```
- (IBAction)setNValueAt1meter:(id)sender
{
self.nValue1m.text = RSSIvalue;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as long as you get the order right.

However it looks to me like `RSSIvalue` should be stored as a number which you format during presentation:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *RSSIvalue;

- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central
 didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral
     advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData
                  RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
{
    self.RSSIvalue = RSSI;
}

- (IBAction)setNValueAt1meter:(id)sender
{
    self.nValue1m.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.RSSIvalue];
    // same as this, only more expensive:
    // self.nValue1m.text = [self.RSSIvalue description];

}
```

Note the use of `self.RSSIvalue`. You could even make it a `long` which is simpler still.

Comment: If i want to use RSSIvalue for an aplication in math say RSSIvalue*3 would it still work if it were saved as a NSString?

Comment: @user2792129 No, you need to store data in the most appropriate data type.  If `RSSIValue` is an integer then don't store it as a string.